# SQL query with foreign keys on three tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have three tables

Table 1. **`color_sets_info`** with `set_id` (PK), `set_name` columns

Table 2. **`colors`** with `set_id` (FK), `color_id` (PK), `color_name`, `color_formula` columns

Table 3. **`mixed_colors`** with `color_id1`(FK), `color_id2`(FK), `color_formula` columns

---

foreign key `colors.set_id` references `color_sets_info.set_id`

foreign key `mixed_colors.color_id1` references `colors.color_id`

foreign key `mixed_colors.color_id2` references `colors.color_id`

---

How to get from **mixed_colors** specific `set_name` or `color_formula` and all related columns:

`colors.color_name` (for `mixed_colors.color_id1`),

`colors.color_name` (for `mixed_colors.color_id2`),

`color_sets_info.set_name` (for first `colors.color_name`),

`color_sets_info.set_name` (for second `colors.color_name`)

`mixed_colors.color_formula`?

---

For example:

```
color_sets_info           colors
+--------+-----------+    +--------+----------+------------+---------------+
| set_id | set_name  |    | set_id | color_id | color_name | color_formula |
+--------+-----------+    +--------+----------+------------+---------------+
| 1      | somename1 |    | 1      | 1        | black      | R0G0B0        |
| 2      | somename2 |    | 1      | 2        | yellow     | R255G255B0    |
| 3      | somename3 |    | 2      | 3        | green      | R0G255B255    |
+--------+-----------+    | 3      | 4        | red        | R255G0B0      |
                          +--------+----------+------------+---------------+

mixed_colors
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| color_id1 | color_id2 | color_formula |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| 1         | 4         | R127G0B0      |
| 2         | 3         | R127G255B127  |
| 3         | 1         | R0G127B127    |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I need to get from **mixed_colors** `color_formula` and two `set_names` and two `color_names` for each mixed color where 1) used only *somename1* and *somename2* color set 2) with *R127G0B0* formula

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or SqlServer? What SQL have you already tried?

Comment: I know how to construct SQL for children, e.g. `SELECT color_sets_info.set_name, color_name, color_formula FROM colors JOIN color_sets_info ON colors.set_id = color_sets_info.set_id`, but stuck with sub-clidrens, especially with two `color_id` in **mixed_colors**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m.color_formula,
    cs1.set_name AS set_name1,
    c1.color_name AS color_name1,
    cs2.set_name AS set_name2,
    c2.color_name AS color_name2
FROM
    mixed_colors m
    JOIN colors c1 ON
        m.color_id1 = c1.color_id
    JOIN color_sets_info cs1 ON
        c1.set_id = cs1.set_id
    JOIN colors c2 ON
        m.color_id2 = c2.color_id
    JOIN color_sets_info cs2 ON
        c2.set_id = cs2.set_id;
```

Or if you prefer you can first collect colors and colorsets into a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_colors AS
SELECT
    color_id,
    set_id,
    color_name,
    set_name
FROM
    colors c
    JOIN color_sets_info cs ON
        c.set_id = cs.set_id;
```

And then query on that:

```
SELECT
    m.color_formula,
    v1.set_name AS set_name1,
    v1.color_name AS color_name1,
    v2.set_name AS set_name2,
    v2.color_name AS color_name2
FROM
    mixed_colors m
    JOIN vw_colors v1 ON
        m.color_id1 = v1.color_id
    JOIN vw_colors v2 ON
        m.color_id2 = v2.color_id;
```